# What are the steps to install Balena Etcher to the 16.04 Launcher toolbar?

Tags: launcher

**Ubuntu 16.04:** Balena Etcher .zip file returns a .AppImage file.  What are the steps to install the .AppImage file so that it can be summoned from the launcher toolbar?

Solutions that utilize native 16.04 functionality are sought.

Update: [Command line instructions](https://www.fosslinux.com/35503/how-to-create-a-live-linux-usb-drive-using-etcher.htm) failure:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61

Executing: /tmp/tmp.RuUWuAhwMh/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443
--recv-keys
379CE192D401AB61
gpg: requesting key D401AB61 from hkps server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 1: unsupported protocol
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: ?
gpg: keyserver communications error: g10err=127
gpg: keyserver receive failed: g10err=127
```

Unable to find package:

```
sudo apt-get install balena-etcher-electron
```

> Reading package lists... 
>   Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... 
>   Done E: Unable to locate package balena-etcher-electron

Comment: @Kulfy  There are numerous solutions.  Please consider posting a link to the one you recommend and any commentary.  I have constrained the question to 16.04.  Thank you

Comment: You need to add the Etcher Debian repository and then install balena-etcher-electron, not just download the ISO. Then you can right click the icon in programs and add to favorites. https://www.fosslinux.com/35503/how-to-create-a-live-linux-usb-drive-using-etcher.htm

Comment: IIRC balena etcher used to create shortcut after the first use.

Comment: Double click the Etcher appimage file. It will offer to create a shortcut.

Comment: @Archisman I doubled clicked on the Escher app image file, it pops a window says “No application found for ‘balenaEtcher-1.5.102-x64.AppImage” and provides me with two options: 1. View all applications 2. Find new applications

Comment: @JuneWang  The etiquette is to ask question or comment to solve the OP problem.  If you are experiencing an issue and seek assistance, then you would be better off creating a new question and if helpful quotes this post to demonstrate you have done your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## AppImage

- You should delete (if these files exist) following files:

  ```
  rm $HOME/.local/share/appimagekit/no_desktopintegration
  sudo rm /usr/share/appimagekit/no_desktopintegration
  sudo /etc/appimagekit/no_desktopintegration
  ```

  Then invoke your app again and allow Etcher creating the `.desktop` file
- Otherwise you can follow [Kulfy's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop). A very simple and fast method is to open the appimage and right click mouse on the icon in the dash and "add to favorites".

If you prefer to install the **usual** way via apt, use the following guide from the [github page](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64):

## APT Install Etcher

Refer to the downloads page for the latest pre-made installers for all supported operating systems.

Debian and Ubuntu based Package Repository (GNU/Linux x86/x64)

- Add Etcher debian repository:

  ```
  echo "deb https://deb.etcher.io stable etcher" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
  ```
- Trust Bintray.com's GPG key:

  ```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
  ```
- Update and install:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install balena-etcher-electron
  ```
- In case you want to uninstall app

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove balena-etcher-electron
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

Comment: For some reason, two etcher (green cube) sit on the launcher when after the application is running.  Not a problem, but odd